# pythons enumerate in go

Tags: go, generator

let's say that I have generator of fibonachi numbers, and I would like to use `enumerate(get_next_fibs(10))` and I would like to have generator of pairs `index, number_from_generator`, I am struggling to find solution with "named return values"

and it's not how it should be done but it's for purpose of learning specific things about generators

```
package main

import "fmt"

func get_next_fibs(ii int) func() int {
    i := 0
    a, b := 0, 1
    fc := func() int {
        i++
        a, b = b, a+b
        if ii <= i {
            return -1
        }
        return a
    }
    return fc
}

func enumerate(iter func() int) func() (index, v int) {
    index := 0
    fc := func() (index, v int) {
        v := iter()
        return
        index++
    }
    return fc
}

func main() {
    iter := enumerate(get_next_fibs(10))
    // iter := get_next_fibs(10)
    fmt.Printf("iter = %T\n", iter)
    for tuple := iter(); tuple != -1; tuple = iter() {
        fmt.Println("tuple:", tuple)
    }
}
```

Comment: What is supposed to be the behavior of `get_next_fibs`?

Comment: @HymnsForDisco if you comment first line of main and ucomment second then program will print next 9 fibonaccis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have few issues in this code sample:

1. You can't have `index++` after return statement. [Use `defer`](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Defer_statements) if you need to do something after `return`-ing.
2. You're missing how variable shadowing works in go. Thus, you're trying to modify a wrong `index` variable.
3. Go doesn't have tuples.

```
...
func enumerate(iter func() int) func() (index, v int) {
    counter := 0
    return func() (index, v int) {
        i := counter
        counter++
        return i, iter()
    }
}
...
func main() {
    iter := enumerate(get_next_fibs(10))
    fmt.Printf("iter = %T\n", iter)
    for i, v := iter(); v != -1; i, v = iter() {
        fmt.Printf("i: %d, v: %d\n", i, v)
    }
}
```

[Playground link](https://go.dev/play/p/1om2eK8N2ii)

Comment: great answer but I wanted to see this detail 
`index = i
v = iter()
return`
overall I managed to reach proper answer + thank you for great remarks

Comment: @quester these are named return values. https://go.dev/tour/basics/7

Comment: yes and I stated in line 3 of question that I wanted to see this solution, overall np because your answer was enough to help me